# Displaying results of $.post in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a following HTML structure, which is a modal pop-up like following:

```
<!-- Left side of the pop up-->

     <div class="pop-state">
               <!-- state -->
               <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                   <div class="pop-first-btn">
                       <a class="check-user" value="<?=$user['id']?>"><?=$user['username']?></a>
                   </div>
               <?php  } ?>
           </div>

<!-- Right side of the modal popup-->
       <div class="pop-brands" >

           <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($brandList); $i++) { ?>
               <div class="pop-city-co" id="brands">
                   <label>
                       <input class="check-city" type="checkbox" name="" value="<?=$brandList[$i]['id']?>" data-id="<?=$i ?>"><?=$brandList[$i]['name']?>
                   </label>
               </div>
           <?php  } ?>
       </div>
```

And when a user clicks on the a link I do the following jQuery event:

```
$('.check-user').click(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post("/user/usersBrands", {userId:user_id}, function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        var brands = $('<div />').append(data).find('#brands').html();
        $('#brands').html(brands);
        console.log(brands);
    });
});
```

I pick up the userId, send it to my function, and then I'd like to update the right side of my popup with the user list, in form of checkbox list... And this is my function that I'm calling:

```
 public function usersBrandsAction(){
        $userId = $this->getRequest()->getPost("userId");
        if(!empty($userId))
        {
            $brandList = $this->getBrandModel()->brandList();
            $this->dieCustomCode($brandList); // it can be echo instead of this or anything that would return me the array of brands...

        }
    }
```

So when I click on the a link, nothing shows up... the console says the #brands is undefined for some reason... Can someone help me out with this ? :/

Comment: you can't have `id="brands"` in `for` loop. Please correct your HTML. Ids should be unique in HTML.

Comment: what you mean by `$('<div />')` ??

Comment: @Andre it says undefined...

Comment: @abhishekbagul that's standard syntax for creating a new `div` element in jQuery

Comment: Do you have some *other* html that is already in the page, ie some that defines `id='brands'`?

Comment: Are you sure it gives 'undefined' and not 'length==0' ?   If you do `$("#id_not_on_the_page')` you get an empty jquery array, *not* "undefined".  At what point does it give undefined? (before you call $.post?)   Also see my other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I suggest to use `append()` instead of `html()` until you really need to replace all the previous data with `.html()` method.

So, instead of

`$('#brands').html(brands);`

use

`$('#brands').append(brands);`

Also, instead of:

`var brands = $('<div />').append(data).find('#brands').html();`

write:

`var brands = $('<div />').append(data);`

Because, once you append your data to the DIV element, you do not need traverse the DOM anymore in your case.

2) Make sure, that you don't have duplication of elements with id "brands" in the DOM.

3) Check if your `"#brands"` or `".pop-city-co"` are not hidden with CSS.

4) I also suggest to use `json_encode` on your PHP side and then parse it on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using like this. It  might work.

```
$('.check-user').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var user_id = $(this).attr('value');
     $.post("/user/usersBrands", {userId:user_id}, function(data){
         //console.log(data);
        var brands  = "<div>" + data + "</div>";
        $('#brands').html(brands);
        console.log(brands);
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay now it prints out the brands in the console.log... but nothing appears in the HTML of the browser?? :/

Comment: Are you getting HTML structure in Console?

Comment: Yes I get <div> data is here... </div> But the data is not well structured at all... I see the array in console.log but it has a mixture of everything inside it lol...

Comment: Is your element '$('#brands')' is present in your HTML ? If it present in your HTML then it definatly the HTML will appear. Just check weather and CSS issue with '$('#brands')', element.

Comment: Can you please check weather your element $('#brand') is present in the HTML when you click. like ' if($('#brand').length > 0){alert($('#brand').length);} ' .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114002/discussion-between-perkes456-and-samir).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about JS but once I tried this and worked for me.

just put the parameter name in quote 'userId'

I am posting this as an answer because my reputation is not allowing me to comment